# Angular 10 tons of build errors when aot=true (production)

Tags: angular, compiler-errors

My Angular project is from a Udemy course "Build An App With Asp.Net Core and Angular From Scratch". I am able to build and run the project without error as long as aot (ahead of time compilation) is set to false but if I set it to true, or run a production build where it is set to true, I get pages and pages of errors with things such as "Can't bind to 'ngClass' because it isn't a known property of 'div'" or "Can't bind to ngModel because it isn't a known property of 'input'" or "Can't bind to 'formGroup' because it isn't a known property of 'form'. Obviously I have all these modules declared and they work exactly as expected in any build (including production) where aot is set to false. I can include code but there's a lot of it and because there are so many errors I have no idea which parts are relevant. (the Github for it is here https://github.com/nightbob3/DIsForDating ). I am using Angular 10.0.8, with a cli of 10.0.8. (Ivy workspace is yes, if that's relevant). The reason I originally set aot to false is because at the beginning of the project I was getting an error in the browser (but no errors in the terminal after running ng serve) that read something like "JIT compilation failed" and the page wouldn't load. Setting aot to false fixed it but I have no idea why, just tried it based on some forum recommendations.

Comment: could you get rid of time-ago-pipe in your app and try to build it again?

Comment: @Andrei Getting rid of the Timeago pipe fixed the problem, thank you. Now I've got to figure out what to do without it but that seems like a much less daunting task.

Comment: if you put this pipe into the project everything should be fine